# How to change a picture by an event in Android?

Tags: android, sdk, battery

I am developing a battery status app and I want to change the battery picture when the battery level of the phone change, for example from 50% to 45% the battery picture should change its status too. How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: 1) google how to get battery status   2) google how to change image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot monitor the battery level in Android, you can only monitor the charging state or significant changes of the battery level. Read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorLevel).

Short form: monitoring the state constantly has a bigger impact on battery life than your app itself, it wouldn't make any sense.

As for changing images, you can use [setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) or [setImageDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) of an `ImageView`.